# Using std::mem_fn, generate wrapper object for Overloaded functions

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, wrapper

In this code:

```
struct Foo {
    /*void display_greeting() {
        std::cout << "Hello, world.\n";
    }*/
    void display_greeting(int i) {
        std::cout << "Hello, world.Greeting #" << i <<std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;

    auto greet = std::mem_fn(&Foo::display_greeting);
    greet(f, 1);
}
```

If I uncomment code for `display_greeting()`, the overload resolution fails at compile time giving error

```
no matching function for call to 'mem_fn(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
auto greet = std::mem_fn(&Foo::display_greeting);"
                                   ^
```

How do I fix this issue, so that I can have both flavors of `display_greeting` func?

Comment: `auto greet = std::mem_fn(static_cast<void (Foo::*)(int)>(&Foo::display_greeting));` Basically, you have to manually pick the correct overload.

Comment: `std::mem_fn<void(int)>(&Foo::display_greeting);` to be a bit less verbose than a cast.

Comment: I cant figure out how to call overload without arguments, it keep giving me errors.

Comment: @FilipKočica - Like this https://ideone.com/igujxt

Comment: @FairyTailTeller thank you, it was in the calling `greet(f, 1);` sorry